# When should I use "and" in Objective-C method names?

Tags: objective-c, coding-style, methods, naming-conventions, naming

The Apple style guides for naming methods say both "Don’t use “and” to link keywords that are attributes of the receiver." and "If the method describes two separate actions, use “and” to link them." In many cases, neither of these conditions apply. For example, let's say I have a function to do some work and call a selector on a target when it is done. Should this be named

```
- (void)findObjectsInBackgroundWithTarget:(id)target andSelector:(SEL)selector;
```

or should this be named

```
- (void)findObjectsInBackgroundWithTarget:(id)target selector:(SEL)selector;
```

In that example, the selector and target are related, but not through being attributes of the receiver. A similar example is to retrieve an object with particular attributes, but the object is not the receiver of the method. Should this function be

```
+ (Thing *)getThingWithName:(NSString *)name andId:(NSString *)thingId;
```

or should this be named

```
+ (Thing *)getThingWithName:(NSString *)name id:(NSString *)thingId;
```

I know this might seem like a minor thing, but it's nice to use the style everyone expects.

Comment: This isn't an answer so I'll leave it as a comment.  I think for the target/selector example, the selector parameter in a lot of libraries is called 'action'.  But that doesn't invalidate your question as a general point.

Comment: I think target/action vocabulary is mostly used for UI-centric code (heavily in NS/UIResponder and NS/UIControl, for example). Selector seems appropriate for callback behavior as above (say, as in NSNotification).

Comment: Since you're asking about method name style: `get...` has a specific meaning in Cocoa; it is _not_ used for general "getter" methods, but only for methods which take a pointer-to-pointer and return an object by reference. See, e.g., [`[NSArray getObjects:range:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BABBGGHJ).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to what Apple says, you should use "and" only if the name of your method describes the action the method does, i.e. `-(void)doThisAndThat`, so in both of your examples you should not use "and" in methods' names.

Comment: And in a design perspective, use "and" in a method name as Apple explains could be considered as lack of cohesion.